# Merge sort - four sorted parts in one array

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I have one array where are 4 sorted parts. For example

```
int array[20] = {1,4,7,8,10,2,3,6,8,11,1,2,7,8,9,3,4,9,10,13}
```

What I need to do is use merge sort on first 2 sorted parts (1,4,7,8,10 and 2,3,6,8,11) and then for second 2 sorted parts (1,2,7,8,9 and 3,4,9,10,13). Then I need to merge these 2 sorted parts into one sorted array.

I tried to use these piece of code, but there is something wrong.

```
void Merge(int *array, int *aux, int left, int right)
{
    int middleIndex = (left + right) / 2;
    int leftIndex = left;
    int rightIndex = middleIndex + 1;
    int auxIndex = left;
    while (leftIndex <= middleIndex && rightIndex <= right)
    {
        if (array[leftIndex] >= array[rightIndex])
        {
            aux[auxIndex] = array[leftIndex++];
        }
        else
        {
            aux[auxIndex] = array[rightIndex++];
        }
        auxIndex++;
    }
    while (leftIndex <= middleIndex)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = array[leftIndex++];
        auxIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex <= right)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = array[rightIndex++];
        auxIndex++;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to modify this, or write it better? Thanks

Comment: "but there is something wrong" - We can't help you if you don't tell us *what* is wrong...

Comment: How do you call Merge? You have four ranges and you can merge two of them at once, not four.

Comment: Normally one would just write a merge sort algorithm (initial order does not matter), but are you trying to write an algorithm for this specific case? Also, you don't show how you call your function.

Comment: try calling this code with left = 0, right = 10 = index of the second one. then replace `leftIndex <= middleIndex && rightIndex <= right` with `leftIndex < middleIndex && rightIndex < right`. What is the output then?

Comment: Do you know where the indices are of the start and end of the sorted ranges?  If so, then use `std::inplace_merge`.

Comment: Why do you have `float *` when the array you're sorting is of type `int`?

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake caused by copy. It has to be int

Answer (score 1):

```
        import java.util.Arrays;

        public class Main {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                int[]  sortArr1 =  merge(new int[] {1 , 4 , 7 , 8 , 10} , new int[] {2 , 3 , 6 , 8 , 11} );
                System.out.println("Merging of sorted array  " +Arrays.toString(sortArr1));

                int[]  sortArr2 =  merge(new int[] {1 , 2 , 7 , 8 , 9} , new int[] {3 , 4 , 9 , 10 , 13} );
                System.out.println("Merging of sorted array  " +Arrays.toString(sortArr2));

                int[]  finalSort = merge(sortArr1 , sortArr2);
                System.out.println("Merging of sorted array  " +Arrays.toString(finalSort));

            }

            public static int[] merge(int[] arr1 , int[] arr2) {

                int[] sort = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];         
                int j = 0;
                int k = 0;

                for(int i = 0 ; i < sort.length ; i++ ) {
                    if(j <= (arr1.length - 1)  && k <= (arr2.length - 1)) {
                        if(arr1[j] > arr2[k]) {
                            sort[i] = arr2[k++];
                        }else {
                            sort[i] = arr1[j++];
                        }
                    }else if(j <= (arr1.length - 1)) {
                        sort[i] = arr1[j++];
                    }else if(k <= (arr2.length - 1)){
                        sort[i] = arr2[k++];
                    }
                }

                return sort;
            }

        }
```

***Output of the program is :***

```
       Merging of sorted array  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11]
       Merging of sorted array  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 13]
       Merging of sorted array  [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to modify this, or write it better? Thanks

Since the ranges are already sorted, and you know where the ranges start and end, use [std::inplace_merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int array[20] = {1,4,7,8,10,2,3,6,8,11,1,2,7,8,9,3,4,9,10,13};

using namespace std;

void MergeSort(int *arr, int start1, int start2, int start3, 
               int start4, int size)
{
   std::inplace_merge(arr + start1, arr + start2, arr + start3);
   std::inplace_merge(arr + start3, arr + start4, arr + size);
   std::inplace_merge(array, array + start3, arr + size);
}

int main()
{
   MergeSort(array, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20);
   std::copy(array, array + 20, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/QuDvGM)